# Can two instructions execute in the same cycle if the same register is used as input and output respectively?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

For example, could these two instructions begin executing in the same cycle or do they interfere with each other?

```
MOV  %RAX, (ADDR)      # AT&T syntax: store rax
POP  %RAX
```

Comment: if it's `movl` then shouldn't it be eax?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: good point, that was totally bogus code.  I assuming it was 16-bit Intel-syntax (dst first, WAW hazard), since hardly anybody uses AT&T syntax for 16-bit code.  POP AX (`popw %ax`) is valid in 64-bit mode and 32-bit modes, but POPL isn't (and this is tagged x86-64), but I still thought it would be more clear to convert the code to valid 64-bit AT&T syntax.

Comment: It was the syntax for Go's assembler, which comes from Plan9 I think. Not the best to use as an example, thanks for changing it. Your rewrite is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they can execute in the same cycle on a modern out-of-order CPU, because they use [Tomasulo's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomasulo_algorithm) for register renaming.  It totally avoids all [write-after-read hazards like this, and also write-after-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)), so out-of-order execution is only limited by Read-after-Write true dependencies.

After register renaming, `pop` will write the new value of the RAX architectural register to a different physical register than the one holding the old value of RAX (which as the input for the store).

The instructions have zero interaction with each other, because the `pop` starts a new dependency chain for the value of RAX.  (Its output is write-only.)  **The `pop` (and following instructions that read/write RAX) could be executed many cycles before the store, especially if the value to be stored is produced by a long dependency chain.**

See also [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/) and other links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

update: I thought you were asking about two instructions that write the same register or read the same register, since your original example code left off the `%` marks, and used AX, so I assume it was 16-bit Intel-syntax.  Leaving this part in as a bonus anyway.

Two instructions reading the same register (read-after-read) is not even a hazard at all.

Intel CPUs before Sandybridge have a limitation on the number of not-recently-modified registers that can be read in the same cycle, but reading the same register multiple times in nearby instructions is not a problem.  (Search for register read port stalls in Agner Fog's microarch pdf, and/or see [this answer where it was relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917429/224132)).

Comment: Fascinating, modern out-of-order CPUs are so deliciously complex :)